# Modularity for determining the number of clusters

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, modularity

The question of finding the number of clusters in a clustering algorithm has been asked a million times. But my question is this: Is it not reasonable to use network modularity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks)) to find the correct number of clusters?

If so, does anyone know if it is a common approach in the different areas of data analysis?